# Creating a chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service

Tags: botframework

I am trying to implement a bot in my website using the botbuilder framework for node.js. The function builder.ChatConnector() get the parameters appId and appPassword, does any one knows where can i found these appId and appPassword? It isn't clear for me in the microsoft documentation. The function is shown above:

[function builder.ChatConnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xheJr.png)
[BotFramework documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/overview/#navtitle)

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your bot in https://dev.botframework.com/ and there you will get those values. Check [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html#registering) article that explains how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information when you create your bot in Azure Bot Service, or when you proceed to register your bot at the **[dev portal](https://dev.botframework.com)**.

Here's a brief walkthrough for registering through the dev portal with the minimum requirements. You'll need to fill out the name, bot handle and description for the bot as indicated below:

[image: Bot Profile]

After this, you can scroll down and click on the button that says "Create Microsoft App ID and password".

[image: Create Microsoft App ID and password]

Once you click on the button you'll be taken to a page with your bot name, your newly-generated App ID, and another button that allows you "Generate a password to continue".

[image: Generate a password to continue]

After you click the button a small window will pop up with your password which you need to keep track of as it is only shown once!

NOTE: For developing and testing using the **[Emulator](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator)**, you don't need this information just yet. You only need the AppID and password when you are making your bot public facing/deploying it.